# PHP Mysql increment db field like a project version

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, increment, versioning

Perhaps i not titled the question right.

But i am curious if it is **build-in** to increment a field each time with +1 in the following format :

Start with 1.0  (or 1.0.0)

eventually at some moment, after many updates the field could be:

2.7.1

Comment: By what logic would it automatically know which component to increment?

Comment: I'd rather define the version as number or string and insert that string on update into the database. Everything else would be kind of odd in my point of view.

Comment: @David Yes that is what i am curious about. I was assuming that could be defined in the sql-statement. Just curious if it possible.

Comment: @HenryW: Well, sure.  If you're writing custom logic to update the value then you can update it to whatever you want.  An `UPDATE` statement does just that... update a value.  This version could be a single string value or a group of integer values which get concatenated for display.  But at that point, what exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but SQL can do it.

There are three incrementing operations in your requirements. 
Let's say your version looks like `Major.Minor.Patch`. You'll need a separate operation for each kind of incrementing operation. And, you need a table column for each one.

Retrieving the version:

```
     SELECT CONCAT_WS('.', Major, Minor, Patch) FROM tbl WHERE whatever;
```

Incrementing the patch:

```
     UPDATE tbl SET Patch = Patch + 1 WHERE whatever
```

Incrementing the minor version and resetting the patch.

```
     UPDATE tbl SET Minor = Minor + 1, Patch = 0 WHERE whatever
```

Incrementing the major version and resetting the minor and patch.

```
     UPDATE tbl SET Major = Major + 1, Minor = 0, Patch = 0 WHERE whatever
```

**Pro tip** It's often the case when designing SQL that you need to thoroughly understand the real-world problem you are solving--you need an accurate data model of your problem.  Then, the SQL is easy.

Comment: That is a very good answer and by it you let me remember  also that each number represents a status of the project itself. I will go work on this one. It opened some doors and i have to change my perspective when the user does an update. lol, you not made it easier for me like that. But it is the good way to do it like that. Thanks!